# Copied Columns Align based on similar data

Tags: excel

I am building a 5-year history where I copy two columns of data from 5 different worksheets.  The column headings are Agency and Amount Billed Year xx.  Each year does not have the same amount of data; for example, if I build the first year and then add another year there can be some Agencies not in the first year or some Agencies in the first year but not in the second year and so forth as I continue to add all 5 years.  I adjusted each column manually to line up the agency name and it was a grueling task.  I tried to find code that would automate the process but all I found were comparing two columns.  I want to start with two columns, add two more columns, add two more columns, and so on and then run code to line up data based on agency name with corresponding amount billed Year xx.

I hope I am clear in my request.  I appreciate any code that I can alter to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You add one column in each worksheet, calling it Year. Fill that in with the year, and then you put the 5 worksheet data in the same sheet, just pasting each worksheets data below the prevoius one. Then you make a simple pivot table out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestion.  I used code instead and it works great.  Here is the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, txt As String, w, x
With Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1)
    a = .Value: .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
        For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            For ii = 1 To UBound(a, 2) Step 2
                If a(i, ii) <> "" Then
                    txt = LCase(a(i, ii))
                    If Not .Contains(txt) Then
                        ReDim w(1 To UBound(a, 2))
                        .Item(txt) = w
                    Else
                        w = .Item(txt)
                    End If
                    w(ii) = a(i, ii): w(ii + 1) = a(i, ii + 1)
                    .Item(txt) = w
                End If
            Next
        Next
        Set x = .Clone
    End With
    For i = 0 To x.Count - 1
        .Cells(i + 1, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count).Value = x.GetByIndex(i)
    Next
End With
With Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    For i = 2 To .Columns.Count Step 2
        .Columns(i).Borders(10).Weight = 2
    Next
End With
```

End Sub